Let $a>1$, find the convergent domain of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left ( z-i \right )^{n}}{a^{n}+n^{2}}$
My problem:
Let $a>1$, find the convergent domain of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left ( z-i \right )^{n}}{a^{n}+n^{2}}$.
My attempt: set $\omega_{n}=\frac{\left ( z-i \right )^{n}}{a^{n}+n^{2}}$, we have:
$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left | \frac{\omega_{n+1}}{\omega_{n}} \right |=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left | \frac{a^{n}+n^{2}}{a^{n+1}+(n+1)^{2}}(z-i) \right |=\left | z-i \right |\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{a^{n}+n^{2}}{a^{n+1}+(n+1)^{2}}=\left | z-i \right |\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{a^{n}}{a^{n+1}}=\left | z-i \right |\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{a}=\left | z-i \right |\frac{1}{a}$
the series is convergent as $L<1\Rightarrow \left | z-i \right |\frac{1}{a}<1 \Rightarrow \left | z-i \right |<a$. Thus, the domain of convergence is the open disk of radius $a$ around $z_{0}=i$.
But I get confused in check if the series is convergent when $L=1$ or $\left | z-i \right |=a$. May I say: when $\left | z-i \right |=a$, we have
$\left | \frac{\left ( z-i \right )^{n}}{a^{n}+n^{2}} \right |=\frac{\left | z-i \right|^{n}}{a^{n}+n^2}=\frac{a^{n}}{a^{n}+n^2}\rightarrow 1\neq 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty $, so the series is not convergent?
Is my argument good enough? Is my convergent domain correct? It's nice to get your suggestions for improvement! Thanks.

Your approach is essentially correct. Some suggestions for improvement:
Say at the start (in words) you're going to apply the ratio test. It's somewhat obvious from writing $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{\omega_{n+1}}{\omega_n} \right|$, but saying why you're starting there makes reading slightly easier.
The ratio test says that if $L < 1$, then the series converges. So where you say $L<1\Rightarrow \left| z-i \right|\frac{1}{a}<1 \Rightarrow \left| z-i \right|<a$, the arrows are really backwards. The correct proof says the series must converge if $L < 1 \Leftarrow |z-i|\frac 1a < 1 \Leftarrow |z-i| < a$. In this case we could just use $\Leftrightarrow$ for each, but in some other limit tests we need to be careful about the direction of implication. This can make a difference when multiplying or dividing by something which might be zero, or taking a square or square root, etc.
This point is too early to say that "the domain of convergence is the open disk". The ratio test tells us that the series converges if $|z-i|<a$ and diverges if $|z-i|>a$. Knowing just that, we can say "the domain of convergence includes the open disk of radius $a$ around $z_o=i$".
Your idea for the $|z-i|=a$ case is correct. To expand it a little and make it more rigorous: If $|z-i|=a$, then $|\omega_n| = \left|\frac{(z-i)^n}{a^n+n^2}\right|$ does not converge to zero, so the complex sequence $\omega_n$ cannot converge to zero and therefore the series does not converge. (It doesn't matter whether $\omega_n$ converges to a non-zero number or doesn't converge at all.)
Finish off the answer with your statement, now proved, "the domain of convergence is the open disk of radius $a$ around $z_o=i$".
(You could also say that if $|z-i|\geq a$ then the terms do not approach zero and therefore the series does not converge. Both the limit of $|\omega_n|$ and the ratio test give the answer for $|z-i|>a$.)
